# Headers that are not next to each other in Microsoft Word page are related

Tags: microsoft-word

So i am preparing my thesis and i created sections, when i tryed to edit a header of a page its kind of apply to other pages that are far from each other, so if i edit the header of chapter III, the chapter III header change but also the second half of chapter IV and V and i can't understand why.

I'm on Microsoft Word 2010, thank you so mych for further help i need to print it tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get what exactly your problem is but, You can try section breaks to differentiate among the chapters/sections in your document

place the cursor at the start of line where your new chapter/section start and click the option (next-page)
Layout -> PageSetup group -> Breaks dropdown -> Next Page

Section break:

[image: Image1]

And then go the Header (double click in the header area)  in the new section, you can see that header says section 2 when you go to header area and make sure that link to previous is not selected(It is selected by default so deselect it).

Unselect the link to previous:

[image: Image2]

This is the most tricky thing, so check it for all the section breaks.

Hope this solves

Comment: I am sorry I thought images will show up directly, but they are posted as links(do check em) and here is a detailed process of doing this https://techforluddites.com/create-different-headers-in-word/

Comment: yes, creating a section for each page that has that problem solved it, but i think there is another thing to it, thanks anyway :)